# Wordpress - wp_rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to write a plugin for WordPress but I'm having some issues with regards to the wp_rewrite functionality.

I want to make one page appear as its many by passing variables via the URL (such as: www.mysite.com/WordPress?variable=helloall)

However I want to keep the permalink structure intact, so i want the URL to appear as such:

`www.mysite.com/WordPress/helloall`

I then want to be able to take the slug and use that the search my database. (like you would using $_GET if I was using the general method i mentioned first)

---

I have found a few tutorials online and as of yet able to get this working. I believe my problem is due to a lack of understand with HOW you write the rules correctly.

I have used this tutorial:

http://www.prodeveloper.org/create-your-own-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress.html

and I have attempted to use the same code for the most part. I am able to set the rules, but they just dont seem to want to work for me

can anyone tell me the correct format to beable to do this?

### Edit

this is my current function

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
    $new_rules = array
    (
        '(.?.+?)/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&page='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),

        '(.?.+?)/(.*?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    // Always add your rules to the top, to make sure your rules have priority
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');

### Solution

I have figured it out, I was going to post this as an answer but it seems I am unable to answer my own questions at this moment in time, so instead I'm editing the original post:

First off, the code I post above is correct, however the reason it was not working is because I was not flushing the rules, I do this with the following code:

```
function ebi_flush_rewrite_rules()
{
global $wp_rewrite;

$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
```

My new problem, was that my code worked a little to well, redirecting ALL pages instead of just the one I wanted, this meant that no child pages would display which is a bit of an issue, I have however solved the problem with one small edit:

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
  $new_rules = array
  (
    '(testpage)/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&page='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),

    '(testpage)/(.*?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
  );
  // Always add your rules to the top, to make sure your rules have priority
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

So my final code regarding the wp_rewrite functionality is as follows:

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
$new_rules = array
(
    '(testpage)/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&page='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),

    '(testpage)/(.*?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
    $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
);
// Always add your rules to the top, to make sure your rules have priority
$wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function query_vars($public_query_vars)
{
$public_query_vars[] = "varname";
return $public_query_vars;
}

function ebi_flush_rewrite_rules()
{
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

I hope this saves someone else some time in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working on e a specific page name, this is for anyone who is having issues in the future:

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
    $new_rules = array
    (
        '(testpage)/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&page='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3),

        '(testpage)/(.*?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&varname='.
        $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
    );
    // Always add your rules to the top, to make sure your rules have priority
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function query_vars($public_query_vars)
{
    $public_query_vars[] = "varname";

    return $public_query_vars;
}

function ebi_flush_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```